# .htaccess pass request on for /UA/ folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is similar to question [mod_rewrite: Being redirected to root folder; I want it to stay in sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457499/mod-rewrite-being-redirected-to-root-folder-i-want-it-to-stay-in-sub-folder)
but the answer there is not working for me.

I have a main site which redirects via an index.php handler, but I want a pre-live test area which is held in a subdirectory `/UA/`

I need requests for `UA/` to pass through and be handled in the sub directory, I have tried both `RewriteRule ^/UA  - [L]` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/UA` in my .htaccess of the main directory but this hasn't worked. I've tried with/without `/'s`

Here are my two .htaccess files:

```
RewriteEngine on
ReWriteBase /

# Redirect to HTTPS site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\-site\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my\-site\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/" [R=301,L]

#Allow UA access
RewriteRule ^/UA  - [L]

#Allow certain file types to access directly
RewriteRule \.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|woff|eot|ttf|svg|ico)$ - [L]

# Catch all
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/UA
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

```
RewriteEngine on
ReWriteBase /UA/

#Allow certain file types to access directly
RewriteRule \.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|woff|eot|ttf|svg|ico)$ - [L]

# Catch all
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

The problem is that the site continues to direct to the Live index.php version not the one in /UA/ with a URI of https://www.mysite/UA/

Comment: How do you that a request like `http://domain.com/UA/` is not being handled by `/MY/.htaccess`?

Comment: When you send `https://www.mysite/UA/` Apache only used `/MY/.htaccess` if `.htaccess` is enabled in server config.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, but I know that the page being returned is generated by /index.php not UA/index.php which is what I want when requested as www.mysite.com/UA/*...

Comment: I have been successfully using .htaccess redirects on the site so far, just not behaving as expected now with the subdirectory - its a shared hosting, so .htaccess is configured.

Comment: Verify whether your `/UA/.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `/UA/.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not for `https://www.mysite/UA/foo` request?

Comment: wow, I think that has solved 90% of it. I did as you suggested and instead of an error it found my UA/index.php (which can handle an unknown page), sooo the problem is only when there is not explicit page request, i.e. mysite/UA  vs. mysite/UA/foo.

Comment: For UA, I can live with this, but would be interested in how to make it work without a specific file request also?  Don't know if you can create a suitable answer so that I can give you credit?

Comment: Well if you didn't get 500 error even after adding some random text there that means `/UA/.htaccess` is not being read and this rewrite is happening from Apache server rewrite rules probably.

Comment: But the only way it could find the correct file is via the rewrite base of /UA/ which is only set in the .htaccess in my subdirectory?

Comment: Rename your `/UA/.htaccess` to something else and then open `https://www.mysite/UA/foo`

Comment: That broke it, so when I effectively took `UA/.htaccess` away it failed to redirect, served up the `index.php` in root.  If I have the .htaccess file there and request `www.mysite.com/UA/` it fails and finds `index.php` in root, if I request `www.mysite.com/UA/foo` it works and finds `UA/index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to always have directory slash on in your root .htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash On
```

Keep `/UA/.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
ReWriteBase /UA/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|woff|eot|ttf|svg|ico)$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: For others exploring this question: view comments on main question for the answer that helped me.  Redirect happens if the path request includes a destination in the subdirectory i.e. `www.mysite.com/UA/foo` works but `www.mysite.com/UA/` does not. Adding `DirectorySlash on` has not fixed this, I think it was already on anyway as it's the  default.  I have accepted this answer as @anubhava's comments helped me solve my particular problem; still curious how to redirect a non-specific file or directory request. Setting DirectoryIndex didn't work.